# Stupid questions, iterating over JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

So a two part question, because I can't solve the first problem, and the hacky work around isn't seeming to work either.

I have a JSON object, and within that object is nested object. I want to manipulate something within a deep layer array.

So to start with, I need to learn how to iterate over keys in an object, but I can't see how you do it.

Say I have an object with objects within it, how do I iterate over these?
If it were an array I would do

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
   {console.log(array[i])}
```

But, because they're words, I can't just i++, so I made an array of the words, then wanted to do the same as above, but

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
   {console.log(jsonObject.array[i]}
```

, but this isnt seeming to work, I just get undefined returned.

Apologies for the poor explaination.

Comment: what does your object look like?

Comment: https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion\?champData\=skins\&api_key\=RGAPI-a9b9e9ab-943d-4d59-b041-c22663d53b4b to be specific, I've been looking at both of those threads for like 2 hours now, the later link returns single characters in my terminal, the first just looks likeJquery?

Comment: No question is "stupid"... "A wise man can learn more from a foolish question than a fool can learn from a wise answer." - Bruce Lee

Comment: Yeah, but some questions can be answered with a simple google, and thats a waste of everyones time, like I'm sure this is

Comment: Well if you actually posted what the JSON looked like, people could help you instead of guessing. Put the JSON in your question.

Comment: @SamStone as you can see in the duplicated question, at least 1300+ SO users don't think this is foolish. There is also people from outside summing 511850+ views. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to get the keys and then you can iterate with those.

```
var keys =    Object.keys(obj);

for(i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++){
   var result = obj[keys[i]];
   console.log(result);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: So would that be `for (Object.keys(myObject)){console.log(*what goes here?*)}`

Comment: updated. See answer and tell me if this works.

Comment: Wow, I forgot a 'var' at the beging of the line where you wrote the keys. I'm so stupid, trying to fix problems that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 'for..in' loop, or, even better, `Object.keys()` handles this well.

[Object.keys() documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
for (var i in myObject) { console.log[i] };
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate using  for (key in obj) {...} syntax.

As in:

```
var t = document.getElementById('myTextField');
var obj = {name:'John',last:'Doe'};
var result = '';
for (key in obj) {
        result += key + '=' + obj[key] + ',';
}
```